# Service Behavior Equivalent in ASP.NET WEB API

Tags: wcf, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, wcf-web-api

I am modifying an existing WCF service to a WEB API.
In the WCF service, we have some operation behaviors that checks the validity of session id passed in SOAP header.Do we have any equivalent for Operation Behaviors in WEB API, which will get invoked before and after actual service call?

Comment: `HttpMessageHandler`s are capable of intercepting ASP.Net Web Api pipeline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In WebAPI it's called ActionFilters, please look at [documentation](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs) about them